# If statement always true, never reaches "else"

Tags: php

I have an IF-Statement which is ALWAYS true.
It is not related to other (similar) issue I found here, that's why I posted it again.

Please see:

```
$us1 = $res->C147;
$us2 = $res->C153;
    if($us1 == $us2){
        $resArr[$i]["updated"] = "SAME";
    }else{
        $resArr[$i]["updated"] = "DIFFERENT";
    }
```

No matter what I enter for $us1 and/or $us2 it will always be "SAME".

`$res->C147` & `$res->C153` are 3 letter strings such as "BRR" or "TOW", coming from an XML. Not sure if relevant:

```
<C147>LIE</C147>
<C150>2</C150>
<C153>BRR</C153>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider explicitly casting to string: `$us1 = (string) $res->C147;
$us2 = (string) $res->C153;` if you're getting these from XML using SimpleXML or XMLReader

Comment: Your `if` statement is fine. The values must be different.

Comment: Please post the output of `var_dump($us1, $us2);` and the code where you originally set those variables.

Comment: I bet 30$ that your XML reader is (silently) failing to parse C147 and C153 and is populating both `$res->C147` and `$res->C153` with an empty string.

Comment: I'd bet that the values are `SimpleXML` objects and not actually strings...

Comment: See var_dump:`object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "JOS"
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#46 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "JOS"
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#87 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "JOS"
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#45 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "LIE"
}` so yes, they are objects, but what difference does that make for the statement?

Comment: `if((string) $res->C147 == (string) $res->C153){` did the trick...